# Can't compile WebKit .NET 0.5 in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webkit, compiler-errors, webkit.net

I'm trying to compile WebKit .NET 0.5 in VS 2010 Professional but I'm getting the error:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'C:\Users\Juan
>   Luis\Desktop\WebKit.NET-0.5-src\bin\Debug\WebKitBrowser.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified."

I tried removing the `WebKitBrowserTest` project from the solution but now I'm getting

> "The type or namespace name 'WebView'
>   could not be found"

errors everywhere. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

replace the .dll in the projects debug folder with the original .dll's. When VS make a copy of the .dll's, it does something wrong, replacing them should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy '\WebKit.NET-0.5-src\bin' to your 'bin' folder.

Answer (score 0):

With me, I can't build whole solution, but it runs when I select WebKitBrowserTest as StartUp project, then Ctrl + F5 (Visual Studio would ask me for rebuild JSCore, just click Yes).

If you see an error like "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID...",this link can help http://dotnetgenetics.blogspot.com/2013/06/retrieving-com-class-factory-for.html